# Java Trying to Overload with generics and other methods

Tags: java

Does it return the more specific type? So does it mean that it will usually try to refer to the method that is not a generic and ONLY if nothing is found it will call the generic.

```
public class Test {


   public static boolean bar(String input){
       return false;
   }

   public static < E > boolean bar(E input){
       return true;
   }



}

public class hi extends Test{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        boolean result = bar("Hi");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: One `bar` is `static`, the other is not. This is neither overloading nor overriding, and should not be done lest you incur the wrath of those unfortunates that have to clean up after you (i.e. maintain your code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of type erasure, the second overload gets compiled to `public static boolean bar(Object input)`. So the more specific `String` overload is selected for `bar("Hi")`.